# Is there any way to center text of table cells with jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I want to make table cells text center during generating PDF using jsPdf. Is there any way to make text align center for pdf using jsPdf(by default it's left aligned).

Thanks and Regards,
Afroz Ali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also convert your document into the actual PDF:

```js
const doc = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');

doc.addHTML(document.body,function() {
    doc.save('html.pdf');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js"></script>

<div>
  <div style="text-align:center">Hello World</div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set alignment in option or as a parameter depends how you craeting pdf,and Post the problem with your trial code otherwise you will get negative response.

```
 var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
    //Alignment based on page width
    doc.writeText(0, 40 ,'align - center ', { align: 'center' });
    doc.writeText(0, 80 ,'align - right ', { align: 'right' });
    doc.writeText(0, 120 ,'align - left '});

    //Alignment based on text container width
    doc.writeText(0, 120 ,'align - center : inside container',{align:'center',width:100});
```

Comment: He is asking for alignment of the inside of the table cell.